# Working wordpress UrlRewrite with no result for google search

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have created some code to rewrite the URL's of a page in my wordpress theme. The url rewrite is working fine, but it seems that google cannot find the different pages.

I'm using following code to rewrite the urls:
Functions.php

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "userid";
return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('user/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=user&userid=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Page.php

```
isset($wp_query->query_vars['userid'])) {
            $user = $wp_query->query_vars['userid'];
```

If anyone know why my page is not showing up in google search i would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google's Webmaster Tool to crawl your website?  If you already have Gail account you can use that to login.

Comment: I will try this and come back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I have tryed to create a .xml sitemap from wordpress and it doesnt find the urls.